# Create and execute stored procedure with parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have four tables:

- dbo.Projects (id, ProjectName, Areas, PaymentSystem, Districts.id, purpose.id, types.id, etc)
- dbo.Districts(id, DistrictsName)
- dbo.Purpose (id, PurposeName) - has residential & commercial
- dbo.Types (id, typName)

I want to select `DistrictsName` where `PurposeName = 'residential'`

This is my code I tried but it does not work ,not sure if it true or false,
this is the result from execute this procedure:

```html
ID DistrictsName PurposeName 
 1   District1    residential
 2   District1    residential
 3   District2    residential
 4   District2    residential

i want it to be like this :
ID DistrictsName PurposeName 
 1   District1    residential
 2   District2    residential
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchResidentialProjects]   
AS
    SELECT 
        dbo.Projects.ID,
        dbo.Districts.DistrictName,
        dbo.Purpose.PurposeName
    FROM 
        dbo.Projects 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Purpose ON dbo.Projects.PurposeID = dbo.Purpose.ID 
    INNER JOIN  
        dbo.Districts ON dbo.Projects.DistrictID = dbo.Districts.ID
    WHERE 
        dbo.Purpose.PurposeName = N'Residential'
```

I'm new to SQL Server so any help is appreciated.

Comment: but why a stored procedure for this?

Comment: How it doesn't work? Is there any errors? not working the way you expected?

Comment: What do you mean by doesnt work? are you sure you have records matching your where condition and joins?

Comment: yes , i have four records executed but DistrictName is not DISTINCT

Comment: i want to select DISTINCT  DistrictName only

Comment: It won't be distinct because 1. You don't have the `DISTINCT` keyword. 2. If there is more than one project per district your district will appear twice

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes i think , i have more one project per district but i want to display only the district name one by one no repeat how i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data you are not interested in the project id - in your sample it has no correlation to any project id. So this is one way to do it.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.Districts.DistrictName,
    'Residential' As PurposeName
FROM 
    dbo.Districts 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM 
        dbo.Projects 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Purpose ON dbo.Projects.PurposeID = dbo.Purpose.ID 
    WHERE dbo.Projects.DistrictID = dbo.Districts.ID
    AND dbo.Purpose.PurposeName = N'Residential'
    )
```

But I think it probably isn't the asnwer you're after, it just helps us highlight what you really want

If you want id to be an arbitrarily increasing number, we can do that but first please tag the version of SQL Server